# How do I return rows from one table based on an ID NOT in another table in SQL (sqlite)?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Hello And THANK YOU ALL!!! (SQLITE)

I have 3 Tables: Trips, Layovers, Flights.  One **Trip** has Many **Flights**, and Many **Layovers**.  All **Layovers** and **Flights** are associated with a **Trip** via the PID.

I need to return Trips That ARE Selected (Trips.PIsSelected=1) AND and EXCLUDE ALL Trips WHERE a FlightNumber IS Present.

```
    SELECT t.* FROM Trips AS t 
    LEFT JOIN Flights AS f ON t.PID = f.PID WHERE 
    (f.FlightNumber <> 1892 AND t.PIsSelected = 1) GROUP BY f.PID
```

The above statement just returns all Trips with t.PIsSelected = 1...  I can do the opposite and the below statement works (But this is not what I want.(Below)).

```
SELECT t.* FROM Trips AS t 
LEFT JOIN Flights AS f ON t.PID = f.PID WHERE 
(f.FlightNumber = 1892 AND t.PIsSelected = 1) GROUP BY f.PID
```

The Above Statement works, and returns results where The Trip Has PIsSelected=1 and a FlightNumber of 1892...  I need to return all the results where the FlightNumber IS NOT 1892.  Thank You.

I Uploaded 2 txt files to Drive (Trips.txt, and Flights.txt)
Column data separated by 2 spaces as per StackOverflow recommended.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/13qJJgxCR11qQ122mW6AJ5c-60VA-O4Vt?usp=sharing

Trips
[image: Trips]

Flights
[image: Flights]

Layovers
[image: Layovers]

Comment: I think none of your code works because of extra bracket ?

Comment: Thank You VBoka.  That was just a typo in this forum. I fixed the typo.

Comment: How is the table Layovers related to your requirement. You don't use it in any of your queries. Post sample data and expected results in tabular format and not images.

Comment: So Sorry forpas. I a noob :(  Got it - Images Bad...  I am not sure I know what the correct format is, but I will look into adding "Tabular Format" data.  The Layover Table is related as I will inner join that table once I figure out why my " <> " is not returning the correct data.  Trying to keep the "Issue" simple.  I was afraid making the issue too complex may result in comments related to something I dont care about. I will remove said Image.  Thank You Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Legendary RB found the answer.  Thank You Rick!!!

```
    SELECT t.* FROM Trips AS t 
    WHERE t.PIsSelected = 1 AND NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT 1 FROM Flights f WHERE f.PID = t.PID AND f.FlightNumber = 1892)
```

Also Thanks yo Emmanuel H. for your leading queries ...
Greatly appreciate...

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to figure it out without some sample data, but if your 2nd query works, maybe use that? For example

```
SELECT * from Trips where PID NOT IN (
    SELECT t.PID FROM Trips AS t 
    LEFT JOIN Flights AS f ON t.PID = f.PID WHERE 
    (f.FlightNumber = 1892 AND t.PIsSelected = 1) GROUP BY f.PID
)tmp and t.PIsSelected = 1
```

Comment: Thank You Emmanuel!  I am trying this out (its not working, but this format of inner select statement may be the key to the answer.   and I am looking at how to add data into StackedOverflow forum - I didnt know I could do that

Comment: I uploaded some data to my Drive.  See Link in original post.  ThankYou!

Comment: I'm having trouble running your query because it has a "group by" but is select from t.*.  Maybe that's causing your issue? Try removing the group by. If you need unique trips try SELECT DISTINCT t.* FROM...

Comment: Thanks Emmanuel !!!- I will try the SELECT DINTINCT.  Its hard to wrap the mind around this query, but seems so simple.    If there is a FlightNumber That matches the <> statement, I need that to remove the entire Trip Row from the returned result (Trips.PID).